# ArcGIS Python Add-In Assistant not updated for ca. 4 years

Tags: arcpy, python-addin

For some time I had not used ArcGIS and I getting myself acquainted with the newer versions. Last time I had used 10.1 and now I am using 10.4.1. I had created some simple Python add-ins with the help of the addin assistant.
Now, I started to create Python add-ins again and I am re-doing what I had done but with the newer version.

I find the documentation of the newer version of ArcMap still points to the same add-in assistant that I used 3 years ago. I did not find new functionalities despite the fact that making modifications to the addin was quite cumbersome in cases like adding buttons, renaming the classes, etc.

Is there any reason why this tool has not been updated?

Is there a new tool that I am not aware of perhaps?

Is this because of ArcGIS Pro?

Are Python add-ins not so much used now?

I read that Python is closing the gap with relation to ArcObjects, but making customizations with .Net still seems to me a better approach, am I wrong?

Comment: I still use the same Python AddIn Assistant, and I do not believe that the low level Python code that it uses needs any updating.

Comment: I wouldn't say ArcObjects is *better*, it's more like a different tool for a different job; not *every* interface is exposed to python but most of the time you don't need *every* interface. You can use ArcObjects in python, there are several good Q&A on this site that cover this topic, which would probably work just fine with only a few objects but if you want something to go *'deep'* or run fast then sticking with a compiled language would be worth the effort.

Comment: I strongly disagree with my question put on hold.

Comment: @polygeo you may be using the same assistant, which is already a kind of answer that no improvements are being made, but I consider that the editing of an addin is very prone to error if one renames buttons, classes, you can not simply replace the code but have to copy manually pieces of code.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question per question. If you choose your most important question to ask first, and it is not seeking opinions rather than facts, then your question should be suitable for re-opening.